# Providing spring configuration from code using CodeConfigurationContext?

Tags: c#, app-config, spring.net, spring.codeconfig

Currently in my app.config I have created a separate section for spring dependency resolution like below and is working fine.

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
    <add key="urlprovider" value="Proxy.DependencyProperty.BaseUrl, Proxy"/>
    <add key="wstimeoutprovider" value="Proxy.DependencyProperty.WebServiceTimeout, Proxy"/>
    <add key="powerreconurlprovider" value="Proxy.DependencyProperty.PowerReconUrl, Proxy"/>
    <add key="credentialprovider" value="DependencyProperty.ServerCredential, Proxy" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

However I would like to provide this via code. So I created the configuration class like this

```
[Configuration]
public class ProxyConfiguration
{
    [Definition]
    public virtual KeyValueConfigurationCollection ConfigurationSettings()
    {
        KeyValueConfigurationCollection collection = new KeyValueConfigurationCollection();
        collection.Add("urlprovider", "Proxy.DependencyProperty.BaseUrl,Proxy");
        collection.Add("wstimeoutprovider","Proxy.DependencyProperty.BaseUrl,Proxy");
        collection.Add("powerreconurlprovider","Proxy.DependencyProperty.BaseUrl,Proxy");
        collection.Add("credentialprovider","Proxy.DependencyProperty.BaseUrl,Proxy");
        return collection;
    }


}
```

and then created the CodeConfigurationContext like below

```
var ctx = new CodeConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.ScanWithAssemblyFilter(assy => (assy.FullName.Contains("Test")));
ctx.Refresh();
```

However I am still getting exception from Spring.root that ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled by code. Error creating context 'spring.root': Error registering object with name...  Could not resolve placeholder 'urlprovider'.
How to resolve this?